# Execute PHP Linux Cron when is at 15'

Tags: php, linux, cron

I want to execute 4 crons. 1.- When it is at 15 minutes, for example, 14:15PM. The other one when it is at 30 minutes, the 3rd at 45 and the last one at 00 o clock. Every day every hours. I need this way because I need that I be executed at 15 minutes exactly, not each 15 minutes for example, at 14:17, 14:32 etc.

I have this code to start:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php
```

And it works every minute, but if I try this:

```
* * 15 * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php
```

Not works, I understand the "15" represents that it will be executed when it is at 15 minutes for example 14:15 or 16:15

Very thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron elements can be lists, so instead of just `15`, you could use a comma delimited list of the four minute-marks you need. Note, however, that the minute field is the **first** field of the format:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php
```

Comment: It works like a charm, implemented, very thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php
```

Will work just fine. Or, if you want to run the code at 15, 30, 45, 00:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php
```

Places:

- 1st - Minutes
- 2nd - Hours
- 3rd - Day of the month
- 4th - Month
- 5th - Day of the week

So, Your example with `* * 15 * *` will work every minute, every hour on 15th every month.

Regards, 
Piotr

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to do it by the four minutes? 15, 30, 45 and 00? The answer of Murenik give me an error

Answer (score 2):

15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php will take care of executing this code at xx:15 hrs i.e. at 14:15, 15:15, 16:15 and so on.
Try this and let me know.

similarly 30 * * * * will take care of xx:30 hrs. You can do the rest.

It shall work.
Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 1):

first one is every 15 mins once run if you want 00:15,01:15,02:15,....23:15 follow second ex;

Ex : 1    `*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php`

Ex: 2     `15 00-23 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/Proyectos/forex/prueba.php`